# Compilation issue with react jsx component

Tags: reactjs

With below code I am getting error at line  9
Syntax error :Unexpected token (9:10)  Can some one tell me the issue with this code and how to fix it.

```
import React from 'react';
import {SelectField, MenuItem, getMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider,Stepper,Step,StepLabel,StepButton,StepContent} from 'material-ui'
    import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
    import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
    import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';

    class StepperComponent extends React.Component{

        state = {
            stepIndex: 0,
        }

        handleNext = () => {
            const {stepIndex} = this.state;
            if (stepIndex < 2) {
                this.setState({stepIndex: stepIndex + 1});
            }
        };

        handlePrev = () => {
            const {stepIndex} = this.state;
            if (stepIndex > 0) {
                this.setState({stepIndex: stepIndex - 1});
            }
        };

        renderStepActions(step) {
            return (
                <div style={{margin: '12px 0'}}>
                    <RaisedButton
                        label="Next"
                        disableTouchRipple={true}
                        disableFocusRipple={true}
                        primary={true}
                        onTouchTap={this.handleNext}
                        style={{marginRight: 12}}
                    />
                    {step > 0 && (
                        <FlatButton
                            label="Back"
                            disableTouchRipple={true}
                            disableFocusRipple={true}
                            onTouchTap={this.handlePrev}
                        />
                    )}
                </div>
            );
        }

        render() {
            const {stepIndex} = this.state;

            return (
                <div style={{maxWidth: 380, maxHeight: 400, margin: 'auto'}}>
                    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme}>
                    <Stepper
                        activeStep={stepIndex}
                        linear={false}
                        orientation="vertical"
                    >
                        <Step>
                            <StepButton onClick={() => this.setState({stepIndex: 0})}>
                                GROUP NAME
                            </StepButton>
                            <StepContent>
                                <p>
                                   Add group name and description selection component here
                                </p>
                                {this.renderStepActions(0)}
                            </StepContent>
                        </Step>
                        <Step>
                            <StepButton onClick={() => this.setState({stepIndex: 1})}>
                                STUDENT
                            </StepButton>
                            <StepContent>
                                <p> Add student component here </p>
                                {this.renderStepActions(1)}
                            </StepContent>
                        </Step>
                        <Step>
                            <StepButton onClick={() => this.setState({stepIndex: 2})}>
                                VERIFY
                            </StepButton>
                            <StepContent>
                                <p>
                                    Add verify group component here
                                </p>
                                {this.renderStepActions(2)}
                            </StepContent>
                        </Step>
                    </Stepper>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default StepperComponent;
```

If I use below alternative syntax then it is not giving me any compilation error but somehow button click event is not working.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            stepIndex: 0,
        };
    }


    handleNext () {
        const {stepIndex} = this.state;
        if (stepIndex < 2) {
            this.setState({stepIndex: stepIndex + 1});
        }
    };

    handlePrev () {
        const {stepIndex} = this.state;
        if (stepIndex > 0) {
            this.setState({stepIndex: stepIndex - 1});
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have

```
state = {
            stepIndex: 0,
        }
```

inside the class, you have to put the state object inside of the constructor

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
            stepIndex: 0,
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error is caused by the fact that the if you want to set an initial state directly you have to do so in the constructor

Modifying the state in all other instances should be done with `this.setState`.

To address why the use of the 2nd syntax of code breaks the `handleNext`/`handlePrev`:

Using ES6 class syntax in React means that inline events are not automatically bound to the component.

Any calls to `this.setState` or `this.state` won't work as expected because the `this` refers to the context of *where* the handler us called: the button.

*Setting initial state and Using **bind** in the constructor*:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    stepState: 0
  }
  this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
  this.handlePrev = this.handlePrev.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I did the modification as suggested but some how it is still not working , If possible could please provide JSFiddle of working sample. This is a code from material Ui website http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/stepper  please check Vertical non-linear stepper. example.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what isn't working (errors/warnings...)?

Comment: it is not firing click event on any of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You need babel preset [**Stage-2**](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) or lower to have functions and variables declared as class properties. The **class property initializer syntax** is part of [es2016 specifications](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) and is accepted by the [**transform-class-properties**](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin.

Well this is a highly experimental feature but you can use it by configuring your `.babelrc`:

either add preset **Stage-2** (`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2`)

```
"presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
```

OR the specific plugin (`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`)

```
"plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
```

After this your original code (as below) can work.

```
class StepperComponent extends React.Component{

    state = {
        stepIndex: 0,
    }

    handleNext = () => {
        const {stepIndex} = this.state;
        if (stepIndex < 2) {
            this.setState({stepIndex: stepIndex + 1});
        }
    };

    // ...
```